# Java: Finding out Dependency Version of Non-Maven

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I am presently dealing with mavenizing our Java-projekts.
I got the jars and the source but no where is listed which dependency version they are using.

I already tried to find some help here but unfortunatly I couldn't.

Greetings

Comment: Have you taken a look into the jar files itself ...in the MANIFEST.MF of the jars often helps...

Comment: I did but it's kind of confusing becouse there is a Specification-Version and a Implementation-Version which one of these is it?

Comment: I think if no version is provided, it gets the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tedious task that I remember well. You can try the following:

1. If you are lucky, there is a `META-INF\maven\` directory inside the jar. Then you can grab the GAV from them.
2. You can also take the SHA1 checksum and search for it in Maven repositories (these often have a search function for checksums)
3. You can use the `MANIFEST.MF`. `Implementation-Version` is a good point to look for.
4. You can compare the classes to the classes of various artifacts from MavenCentral to figure out which is the most similar.